# Local SVN repository

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I created a folder for my SVN local repository. It works fine, but I have a question about it:

When I open the SVN folder I see different files like Conf, Hooks, Locks, Db.

But I don't see my projects which I did save in that folder.

When I use Visual Studio to open my SVN projects, I can see (and open) my projects from the SVN folder, but if I access the SVN folder without visual studio I can't see my projects.

Is this normal? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your project-files are stored somewhere inside the db folder. E.g. in the revs folder, you will have one file per revision/version.

But you don't work directly inside the repository folder. Instead, you checkout a working copy, into a different local folder. That's where you can edit files and make your changes.

The repository is where you store (commit) each revision of your locally modified files. Instead of in a local directory, the repository could also live on a server (where you would access it via http for example).

I assume, you are using [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) (if not, please have a look at it). Have a look at it's documentation. It should answer your questions (e.g. "[basic concepts](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-qs-basics.html)" or "[daily use guide](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug.html)").

Comment: Thank you. I use TortoiseSVN indeed. Thought it was possible to see and open the projects in the SVN file.

Comment: @xVizzi: you can view inside the repository using TortoiseSVN's repository browser. But you can't edit files directly inside the repository (you'll have to checkout a working copy).

Answer (score 2):

You have created repository right now. If you want to explore your project you should create a Checkout to that repository.

If you are using TortoiseSVN you can do this by clicking right mouse button insige folder > SVN Checkout... and put your repository url into "URL of repository" (if your repository is on local disk use file:/// instead of http://)